# Configuring SAX parser

Tags: java, android, sax

I am configuring the SAX parser to read the RSS feed. Here is how it looks:

```
public void processFeed(){
        try{
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();

            InputStream stream = new URL(url).openStream();

            XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader();
            reader.setContentHandler(this);

            reader.parse(new InputSource(stream));
        }catch(Exception e){
            errorOccured = true;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that an error occurs and the boolean `errorOccured` is set to true. Can someone please tell me why this is generating an error ?

Comment: Can you print e's stacktrace?

Comment: You should output the exception e.g. using a logger. It should give you all the information you need to fix this.

Comment: @flup There is no stack trace. And there is something in `LogCat` which says `error opening trace file: no such file or directory`

Comment: @Stephan how can I use that?

Comment: Strangely enough, `e.getMessage()` returns null

Comment: sax pull parser at link if u want to look over : https://github.com/rowntreerob/gpsclipper/blob/master/src/com/b2bpo/media/geophoto/ClientCustomSSL.java

Comment: @Stephan `MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.`

Comment: Solved with the help of `Mykong`'s tutoriakl

Answer (score 2):

You have problem in this,

```
InputStream stream = new URL(url).openStream();

            XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader();
            reader.setContentHandler(this);
```

What's your url?